# How to Explode the string in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, explode

I want to explore the following string which I am fetching from the database in CodeIgniter using a foreach loop. Actually, I am using a double delimiter to differentiate tags like SQL and MySQL because LIKE "%sql%" will return MySQL results as well. Should be LIKE "%|sql|%"

```
|login||background||signup||material-design|
```

I tried the following code but no success.

```
$snippettag_id = explode('|', $snippet_tags);

    foreach($snippettag_id as $tag_id) {
    $tag_name = $tag_id;
    $this->db->or_like('snippets_name', $tag_name);
    }
```

Comment: Now, what is the error or issue?

Comment: why there is two delimiters `||` in a string?

Comment: Instead of solving this, you should probably normalize your database...

Comment: Actually, I am using a double delimiter to differentiate tags like SQL and MySQL because  LIKE "%sql%" will return MySQL results as well. Should be LIKE "%|sql|%"

Comment: Then please change the delimiter for exploding from `|` to `,` and save data  i.e `|sql|,|Mysql|,|login|` so you can achieve your output

Comment: Okay then How can i explode with |sql| , |Mysql| , |login|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with same `delimiter` and `symbol` in text, Here you need to `replace` your delimiter in `db` and in `explode()`, Try to save `,` instead of `|` as delimiter

```
$str = "|sql|,|Mysql|,|php|,|C#|,|C++|";//DB string
echo'<pre>';echo $str;
$strArray = explode(',', $str);
echo'<pre>';print_r($strArray);die;
```

Output:

```
|sql|,|Mysql|,|php|,|C#|,|C++|

Array
(
    [0] => |sql|
    [1] => |Mysql|
    [2] => |php|
    [3] => |C#|
    [4] => |C++|
)
```

Apart from solution

> you should probably normalize your database it will more reliable and easy to do searching in future

Comment: Yes Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you need the  output as you mentioned above without using , characters so you can still do that easy

First run your query normal without any modification so results will be

```
$result = "login background signup material";
```

After that use explode with,

```
$snid = explode("," , $result);
```

Now you need | in your result you can do the following

```
$finalresult = str_ireplace(",", "|", "$snid");
```

Now output have  |  instead of ,